# Array merge: use foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-merge

I have 2 arrays:

```
$im=explode(",", $data['products']);
$imi=explode(",", $data['period']);
```

which are associated:

```
$data['products'] = balon,globo,sesta
$data['period'] = 1,1,2
```

so when I merge the result it is:

```
Array ( [0] => DS Basic [1] => DS Pro [2] => DS Start [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 2 )
```

The problem is that I need it to be associated like this:

```
DS Basic = 1 , DS Pro = 1 , DS Start = 2
```

I'm using `array_merge($im,$imi)`

How can I do this using `foreach`?
I would like this:

```
Array ( [0] => DS Basic [1] => DS Pro [2] => DS Start)
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 )
```

So when I use it it can be like

```
using foreach

DS basic has a period of 1

DS pro has a period of 1

DS start has a period of 2
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($im)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is **combination** and not **merge** ;) have look at php's manual on [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) .

Please not considering your desired result keeps one set of data as the keys (values from products array in your example), you are not suppose to have duplicated values, or you will lose them

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the merged result as follows:

```
$merged = array_merge($im,$imi);
$period = array();
// Loop through the merged items
foreach ($merged as $k=>$v) {
  // Check if the value is an integer
  if ((int)$v) {
    // Move this value to the period array
    $period[] = $v;
    // Remove it from the merged array
    unset($merged[$k]);
  }
}
// Reindex the merged array to revalue the keys
$merged = array_values($merged);
// Test the output
echo '<h1>Merged Array:</h1>';
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($merged);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<h1>Excess Array:</h1>';
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($period);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$merged = array();
if (count($im) != count($imi)) {
    print "custom merging is not possible...";
}
else {
    for($i=0 ; $i<count($im) ; $i++) {
        $merged[$im[$i]] = $imi[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do foreach

```
    $newArr = [];
    foreach($im $key => $val)
    {
        $newArr[] = [$val[0] => $imi[$key][0], $val[1] => $imi[$key][1], $val[2] => $imi[$key][2]];
    }
    print_r($newArr);
```

Or combine it:

```
  $result = array_combine($im, $imi);
```